# I need to create an attribute table GeoServer

Tags: geoserver, layers, attribute-table

I have imported a layer from PostGIS, contains many values from many sites (locations).
My goal is to let the user see all the values as soon as he clicks on the location (on the map), SO I do not want to show all the values of the sites, in the same time I want to link the sites with the value.

I could import the layer of the locations as points. Then I would like to connect the attribute table (values with the sites id) with the locations without any duplication?

How can I do this?

Comment: You are looking for GetFeatureInfo - any of these [questions](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/getfeatureinfo+geoserver) will likely answer your question

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE! We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site. Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that. Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works